# It's a simple query, but I do not know why

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(1)
FROM (
  SELECT
      TO_NUMBER( EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE'2017-01-01') - EXTRACT(YEAR FROM            
      TO_DATE(BIRTH_DAY, 'YYYYMMDD')) ) AS AGE,
      XX.*
  FROM MEMBER_INFO XX
  WHERE BIRTH_DAY IS NOT NULL  
) XXX
```

Which executes without error. However, if I add this to the end of the query:

```
WHERE XXX.AGE >= 30 AND XXX.AGE < 50
```

I get the following error:

> 101840. 00000 -  "input value not long enough for date format" (ORA-01840)

Why does this error occur?

Comment: What error message???

Comment: ah im sorry . message is **01840. 00000 -  "input value not long enough for date format"**

Comment: what do you mean "add a condition"? Can you please edit your question to show the query that works and the query that doesn't work. We are not mind readers; I for one don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Corrected the question.

Comment: Operations are done in different orders depending on the query plan. You have an invalid value in `BIRTH_DAY` which is being applied to the `TO_DATE` function _before_ the filter is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a condition on `AGE`, the calculation `TO_DATE(BIRTH_DAY, 'YYYYMMDD')` is unnecessary to perform to produce the output. The optimizer removes all unnecessary operations, so the query is optimized to simply:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MEMBER_INFO
WHERE BIRTH_DAY IS NOT NULL
```

This is similar to the way many compilers work - they remove chunks of code when it is certain that doing so does not change the outcome of execution.

However, with the condition in place, the calculation must be made and unfortunately you have a value for `BIRTH_DAY` that cannot be parsed as a `YYYYMMDD` date, because it is too short - hence the error.

You could avoid this error by changing the inner condition to:

```
WHERE LENGTH(BIRTH_DAY) = 8
```

which would still also exclude `NULL` values.